# Add to width using setInterval

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add to the width of the element everytime the setInterval function is invoked

```
function setProgress(){
  var bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  var width = 20;
  bar.style.width += width + 'px';

  //console.log(bar.style.width);
}

window.onload = function(){
  setInterval(setProgress, 10);
}
```

I tried using parseInt(), but everytime I console.log() to the window i see the same width. My end goal is for the width to increase by 20

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `px` part from `width` style and then cast string to number before incrementing it:

```
function setProgress(){
  var bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  var width = 20;
  bar.style.width = Number(bar.style.width.replace('px', '')) + width + 'px';

  //console.log(bar.style.width);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `width` a global `var`, like shown below:

```
var width = 0;
function setProgress(){
     var bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
     width+= 20;
     bar.style.width += width + 'px';
     //console.log(bar.style.width);
}
window.onload = function(){setInterval(setProgress, 10);}
```

Also, you should specify the max width to prevent the progress bar moving outside the working area (for example, modifying the increment line: `if(width<500) {width+= 20;} else {return;}`).

*Alternatively*, you can use your original solution by adding couple more statements, namely: removing the "px" unit from style property `bar.style.width`, then parsing it (converting to Number), then incrementing it and then adding "px" (otherwise, "+" operator will cause a concatenation of strings with output like: 20px20px, 20px20px20px, etc). Such alternative solution will slow down the process and put additional load on CPU (thus, it's not recommended).

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: this was my inital attempt but the width just stays at 20px doesn't increment in 20's

Comment: Do not confuse var width (numeric value) with CSS property bar.style.width, which contains a number with unit px added (e.g. 20px). You can remove 'px' and then parse the numeric part (as done in @dfsq solution), or use my solution, which does not require any parsing and additional string operations, so it should run faster with less load on CPU. Best regards,

Comment: yes i haven't what i don't understand is on the first attempt bar.style.width = "20px" and then setInterval fires again it will look like "20px20px"

Comment: I have extended my answer with explanation regarding that issue, possible solution and brief comparative analysis. Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `width` returns a string with units.

Instead, consider storing the number of pixels in a variable:

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar'),
    width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(bar).width);
setInterval(function() {
    width += 20;
    bar.style.width = width + 'px';
}, 10);
```

```js
var bar = document.getElementById('progress-bar'),
    width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(bar).width);
setInterval(function() {
  width += 20;
  bar.style.width = width + 'px';
}, 200);
```

```css
#progress-bar {
  background: #0f0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='progress-bar'>Progress bar</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

var width = 0;
            function setProgress(){
            var bar = document.getElementById('bar');
            width+= 20;
            bar.style.width = width + 'px';
           
           console.log(bar.style.width);
           if(width==200){
             width=0;
           }
          }
            window.onload = function(){ 
                setInterval(setProgress, 1000);
            }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).